# User as scoped service in ASP Net Core - a bad practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, blazor

In my ASP Net Core Application I need to often access and edit user-related data, that is stored on the database. Generally my approach is the following:

- Inject the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationStateProvider` in a scoped service that can manipulate the data (lets call that service `UserEditService`)
- Get the username of the current user from the provided `AuthenticationState` with `AuthenticationState.User.Identity.Name`
- Inject `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<AppUser>` and use it to load the user from the database by name.
- Save a reference of the `AppUser` instance in the `UserEditService`
- Manipulate and save said instance

The problem is that I pretty much copy and paste the same code in a few of my services and I am wondering if it is not a better idea to just load the `AppUser` object as a scoped service in the app and then inject it in all services that require user access. I haven't found projects where people do that and it makes me think that maybe it is a bad practice.
Is this the case and if so why? Is there a better way to manage user-related data in ASPNetCore?

Comment: ASP.NET Core already manages user data, as a scoped service. The `AuthenticationState.User.Identity.Name` has meaning only in the scope of a single request. DbContext instances are scoped by default

Comment: `I haven't found projects where people do that` on the contrary, all projects that use ASP.NET Core Identity use scoped services simply because Identity applies only to a request's scope. All *good* tutorials show DbContext instances used as scoped services by using `AddDbContext`, which gives you "transaction-per-request" semantics: if you don't want to persist changes, just don't call `SaveChanges`.

Comment: I guess I was unclear. I am asking about using the `AppUser` object itself as a scoped service, not the DbContext.

Comment: If `AppUser` is a data object, it'd be better to hide its retrieval behind an abstraction (e.g. `IAppUserProvider`) instead of injecting that object into constructors of your application components. [This article](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/) describes in more detail why that is and what the alternatives are.

Comment: Also if someone could hit me up with a like would be awesome. I've been using Stack Overflow for years now, but I rarely post anything and it is quite annoying not being able to even hit a like on a good answer.

Comment: @leSyndrome, when the AuthenticationState becomes invalid, say, as a result of the .AspNetCore.Identity.Application cookie getting expired, what will your service return when the current user does something that involves the service. Note: As long as the user is within the space boundaries of the SPA he can access protected assets, though he's not authenticated...but what would your service return???

Comment: I do not support persistent authentication, so (correct me if I'm wrong) I assume that the `AuthenticationState` is going to have the same lifetime as my service - scoped I.e. for the whole session and the session only. So if the service exists, there is an `AuthnticationState`. If the user is logged in, the `AppUser` instance can be loaded from the db and returned. Else the service notes that the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `AppUser` consists of runtime data, although it is certainly possible to inject it into the constructors of its consumers, injecting runtime data during object construction as a few troubling downsides. It

> *causes ambiguity, complicates the Composition Root with an extra responsibility, and makes it extraordinarily hard to verify the correctness of your DI configuration. Instead, let runtime data flow through the method calls of constructed object graphs.*

Instead prefer injecting an abstraction that allows retrieving that `AppUser` at runtime, for instance using an abstraction as follows:

```cs
interface IAppUserProvider
{
    AppUser Current { get; }
}
```

For a more detailed discussion about the downsides, take a look at [this article](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/) of mine. (the quote is from that article)

That said, although there are downsides to this approach, that doesn't per se makes it a bad practice or anti-pattern. That's because there are multiple ways of looking at the use of runtime data. There are two competing Composition Models that can be used; one where the capturing of runtime data into components is preferred, and another where the storage of runtime data *outside* the object graph is preferred. You can read more about these competing models [here](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/compositionmodels/).